# Creating print mockups in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mockup

I am very new to working with Illustrator. So, basically, I have this stock image I downloaded from Adobe stock - I have no idea how to put my own images inside the pages! As you can see it is an AI file. I saw that you can do this with Smart Objects in Photoshop but wondering if I can do something similar in AI?

Thank you!!! [image: Pages I want to Fill]

Comment: HI Cayla, welcome to GD.SE! Have you tried using Envelope Distort?

Comment: *Really* difficult to give any direction without direct access to the file, which is sort of off topic here. *Basically*, copy a shape and use that copy as a clipping mask to mask actual content. But depending upon *how* things are constructed, you may need to merely utilize layers wisely.

Comment: I think it would probably be easier to create the actual mockup in Photoshop, which has more effective methods to enable you to distort a page realistically so that it can fit a curved sheet like that. You could even import both the blank book, and any artwork in AI format as Smart Objects in Photoshop, and apply a warp transform.